# Configuring DNS zone file

Tags: domain-name-system

I have created a DNS zone file called 'goodday.zone' and trying to resolve the domain name to an local IP address '10.25.232.142' . But this is not resolving as desired. Please tell me your suggestions .

Here is how the file looks like. Zone file name goodday.zone

```
$TTL 3H
@       IN SOA  @ goodday ( 
                                        0       ; serial 
                                        1D      ; refresh
                                        1H      ; retry 
                                        1W      ; expire
                                        3H )    ; minimum 
        NS      goodday 
        A       10.25.232.142 
        AAAA    ::1
```

Comment: What commands are you running to show that it is not resolving as desired?

Comment: The best suggestion I can make is to stop what you're doing and learn about DNS.

Comment: What @JohnGardeniers said.  I strongly recommend you acquire and read [the cricket book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100575.do)

Answer (score 2):

Learn about DNS basics first,refer to http://linuxconfig.org/linux-dns-server-bind-configuration.
you need to set up NS and A record for your domain "goodday" after you set up these you need to restart bind.